# Please let me know the meaning of this sentence "putting things together for it to sleep in"

Tags: meaning

It is a part of drama. One man said like below and I don't understand the bold part.

FYI, A is cheif of police and his wife is pregnant now. Now A is telling this to other policemen.

> A: Because you're the ones who got all up in her head about us not being prepared. Now I’m taking baby classes and babyproofing the house, **and putting
>   things together for it to sleep in**.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it must be either the crib (a DIY one?) or the baby room. (The "it" in your sentence is the baby.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be paraphrased as "assembling furniture in which the baby will be able to sleep."

First, expectant parents often will refer to the coming child as "it" in the early stages of pregnancy, since the sex of the child is unknown.

Second, furniture such as cribs are often purchased unassembled, and it's up to the parents to assemble it, "putting things together".

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase is referring to a

> **baby's crib**

a safe place for babies to sleep.

It seems to be implied that this is their first baby: taking prenatal classes, baby proofing, and also assembling various *infrastructure* to await the arrival of the baby: diaper changing station, crib, various accessories to go with the crib, bottle warmer, bouncer / rockers, diapers, wipes, bottles, steriliser, baby monitor.

Anyone with kids will tell you it can be daunting.

Baby cribs, like adult beds, by their very nature usually do not come preassembled.
Because of their inherent size they are usually flat packed and **need to be assembled**.  Various choices also exist for mattresses, canopies, mobiles, rectangular or oval shape, on rollers or stationary, etc...